# Asignar los tiempos de respuesta a cada pregunta en un cuestionario de Moodle usando groupby

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

Estoy empezando a usar pandas y me he atascado en un problema que, seguramente, sea una tontería pero no veo como salir.

La idea es sencilla: para los datos de registro de un examen de Moodle saber cuánto tiempo ha empleado en cada pregunta el alumno. Tras procesar el log original de moodle, puedo crear una BD de este tipo

Datos de ejemplo (2 alumnos, 4 preguntas)

```
import pandas as pd
original= [{"Student":"S1","Send":"0:00:00"},{"Student":"S1","Send":"0:01:00"},{"Student":"S1","Send":"0:02:00"},{"Student":"S1","Send":"0:04:00"},{"Student":"S1","Send":"0:05:00"},{"Student":"S2","Send":"0:00:00"},{"Student":"S2","Send":"0:02:00"},{"Student":"S2","Send":"0:04:00"},{"Student":"S2","Send":"0:04:00"},{"Student":"S2","Send":"0:05:00"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(original)
df['Send'] =pd.to_datetime(df['Send'], format='%H:%M:%S') - pd.to_datetime(df['Send'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.normalize()
df['diff'] = df.sort_values(['Student','Send']).groupby('Student')['Send'].diff()
df
```

donde Send es la hora de envio de la respuesta y diff es el tiempo entre un envío y el siguiente:

```
   Send    Student     diff
0 00:00:00      S1      NaT
1 00:01:00      S1 00:01:00  # Send[1]-Send[0]= Tiempo de respuesta de S1 a P1
2 00:02:00      S1 00:01:00
3 00:04:00      S1 00:02:00
4 00:05:00      S1 00:01:00
5 00:00:00      S2      NaT
6 00:02:00      S2 00:02:00
7 00:04:00      S2 00:02:00
8 00:04:00      S2 00:00:00
9 00:05:00      S2 00:01:00
```

Mme he atascado a la hora de crear un nuevo dataframe similar a este, donde se agrupe por pregunta los tiempos de respuesta

```
  Student | P1      | P2      | P3      | P4      
 ---------|---------|---------|---------|--------- 
  S1      | 0:01:00 | 0:01:00 | 0:02:00 | 0:01:00 
  S2      | 0:02:00 | 0:02:00 | 0:00:00 | 0:01:00
```

Cualquier pista es bien recibida. Gracias.

Comment: Cómo identificas a qué pregunta pertenece cada tiempo? Es en el orden que aparecen?

Comment: Sí, es el orden en que aparecen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes una estructura dónde:

- Los datos están ordenados por estudiante, pregunta, hora inicia y hora finalización
- Tienes siempre filas para todos los estudiantes y preguntas

Se me ocurre que podrías hacer algo así:

```
df['RN'] = df.groupby('Student').rank(method='first') - 1
df['diff'] = df['Send'].diff()
preguntas = df.loc[df['diff'] >= pd.Timedelta(0), ['Student', 'RN', 'diff']]

print(preguntas)

  Student   RN     diff
1      S1  1.0 00:01:00
2      S1  2.0 00:01:00
3      S1  3.0 00:02:00
4      S1  4.0 00:01:00
6      S2  1.0 00:02:00
7      S2  2.0 00:02:00
8      S2  3.0 00:00:00
9      S2  4.0 00:01:00
```

Como se puede observar hemos:

- numerado las preguntas mediante `rank()`
- Calculado la diferencia de cada fila con la anterior y eliminado los inicios de cada grupo de preguntas.

Lo que restaría es pasar este formato "largo" a un "ancho":

```
preguntas_wide = preguntas.pivot(index='Student', columns='RN', values='diff')

print(preguntas_wide)

RN           1.0      2.0      3.0      4.0
Student                                    
S1      00:01:00 00:01:00 00:02:00 00:01:00
S2      00:02:00 00:02:00 00:00:00 00:01:00
```

O en su defecto: `preguntas_wide.reset_index()` para tener una salida más "plana".

Comment: Gracias. Esta solución me sirve perfectamente. Y he aprendido algo nuevo.